# React-Native Code doesnt execute

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't find what's wrong in here: https://hastebin.com/fuwofavuso.scala (I can't post it here, and I didn't want to indent all lines).

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TextInput, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { Constants, BlurView } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 200, width: 300 }}>
        <InputText/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class InputText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: 'lel',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <Text value={this.state.text}></Text>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Unknown Snack', () => InputText);
```

My error is:

undefined is not an object evaluating _reactnative.appregistry.registerComponent()

I am running it on Expo Snack

Comment: *"didnt want to indent all lines"* – highlighting the code and clicking one button is too much effort?

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: Honest word of advice;  When asking someone else for help, you ought to put in as much effort as you expect to receive in return.  You've put your code paste behind a link, and given no indication of what attempts you've already made to solve this problem.  So I'll give you an answer of equal effort;  "It looks like your import of the AppRegistry component isn't working".

Comment: please upload your complete code, I can't find where did you use the `appregistry.registerComponent()`.

Comment: @VahidBoreiri it doesnt work also with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/appregistry.html#registercomponent), `registerComponent` function has two arguments that the second argument is your main component that in your case the name of component seems to be wrong (your problem may be because of this). I think your code should be like this:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('yourAppKey', App);
```